# How to open a project in Docker in PhpStorm?

Tags: docker, phpstorm

I have a PHP project in a Docker container. I ran it and it works.

Question: How do I open this project in PhpStorm so that I can edit the files?

I read that I can connect to container via SSH. So where can I get login, password and an IP address to Docker container?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely possible and I see nothing wrong with using Docker for local development.  In this case, I think the best way to achieve what you want is to mount the Docker file directory as a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) on your computer.  You can do this within your docker-compose.yml (assuming you are using one) by adding something like this...

```
volumes:
  - ./foo:/var/www/html
```

Change `foo` to whatever you like and `/var/www/html` would be the path within the Docker container files that you want to edit.  You will then be able to see the "foo" directory on your computer next to your docker-compose.yml file and when you open it you should have direct access to the files you need to setup PhpStorm to point to as you normally would.

Of note... I'm using MacOS so if you are using Docker on Windows I believe you need to make additional accommodations.

Comment: if you use this with drupal on windows you get 16 seconds time to first byte .. if everything is in the container(no mount) its 280ms time to first byte ... looking for a solution to that

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not impossible, but I think the workflow is upside down. You build a container to run it, not to distribute projects for others to edit. Yes, you can run a SSH service inside your container so you can connect to it, but if that's not the containers main purpose then I'd advice against it. Consider a container's resources to be encapsulated and for a reason.

Having a container for the sole purpose of distributing a "non-running" php-storm project sounds weird. It's more likely that you actually want to mount your own project into said container that is running a web-server or php etc. If you tell us more you can probably get a better answer.

Anyway, you can copy files from the container using `docker cp`

```
docker cp CONTAINER:SRC_PATH DEST_PATH
```

And you can run commands with `docker exec` and even start up a shell to make changes (this is pretty much the "docker ssh" you are asking for - but it's not intended for your IDE to connect and make changes with):

```
docker exec -it <mycontainer> bash
```

To answer part of your question:

> So where can i get login, password and ip-address to docker-container?

```
> docker ps   # Shows running containers
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                            NAMES
0bd4e5f2d116        samples             "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   8 hours ago         Up 8 hours          192.168.1.10:8083->80/tcp        samples
e021f9bc74c4        nginx:alpine        "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   10 days ago         Up 8 hours          80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   web
```

Then when you know the container id:

```
> docker inspect e02
* Shows lots of info about the container, including network and IP. (However login and pass not so much) *
```

---

Perhaps you are thinking of `docker-machine` which lets you configure connections to remote (and local) machines which runs docker images. `docker-machine` has a `docker-machine ssh` command that lets you connect directly to that machine. Having connected, you still need to use `docker exec ...` to access your running containers so it probably won't help you much. (You use docker-machine to push containers to remote machines and also start/stop containers remotely).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I got this project for support. I just need sometimes to make some changes .

https://image.prntscr.com/image/OxDekdTuTxmkrQDUB2lraw.png
I found the shared folder in the project with the docker-settings. And "webroot" folder contains the files I need. But when I edit them nothing changes.
How can I synchronize it with the docker-container?

Comment: I would mount the local webroot over the one in the container. Something along the lines of `docker run -v c:\Users\Andrey\dev\windows\magento2\webroot:/var/www/webroot imagename ls /var/www/webroot` (I've had trouble with windows-paths before so I'll not make any garuantees here). And I'm guessing wildly at the container path .  Mounted folders are only local so I would build a image of my own (or rebuild if I had all the files) to persist changes. (There is also [docker commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) to create a new image from a container’s changes)

Comment: I would also learn the basic docker commands and use them instead of trusting the jetbrains docker-tools. There's a lot of magic going on behind the curtains (at least if you use docker-compose). A lot of my problems just went away when I stopped using those. (and I love webstorm and use it daily.)

Answer (score -1):

forward SSH port 22 to a new port (perhaps 2233) and then use phpstorm built-in ssh (TOOLS -> SSH)

https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/08/using-the-phpstorm-built-in-ssh-terminal-and-remote-ssh-external-tools/